# Intersect points remaining after deleting line from gradient mesh

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Ok I've been using the Gradient Mesh tool of late, and am pretty happy with it, it's a great tool! On one of my pieces however I need to restructure the mesh, and so I delete a line using  Alt+Click (with mesh tool selected), but the points created by that line remain - causing the line to be bent.

How do I delete a line as well as the points created by that line?

Here is a screenshot of what I mean:
[Screenshot](http://www.vertaxe.com/remaining_intersect_point.jpg)

My cursor is on one such point, and I can't find a way to remove it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok what I'm referring to are called 'knots', and I've just found a super plugin - [Mesh Tormentor](http://vectorboom.com/load/articles/web_roundups/mesh_tormentor/13-1-0-14)!

It does what I'm asking for and loads more.

Answer (score 0):

That point looks like a regular anchor point on the enclosing path. A mesh point would have at least three intersecting line segments.

You can't delete an anchor point with the mesh tool.

Comment: I found out the actual term for a point like that, its called a 'knot', and its not deletable without the plugin as far as I'm aware.

Comment: One of the lovable things about these tools we work with is there is ALWAYS something new to learn! That plug-in is a good resource. Don't forget to accept your answer, now you've given it. :-)